# Capture and display console output at the same time

Tags: .net, redirectstandardoutput

MSDN states that it is possible in .NET to capture the output of a process **and** display it in the console window at the same time.

Normally when you set StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; the console window stays blank.
As the MSDN site doesn't provide a sample for this I was wondering if anyone would have a sample or could point me to a sample?

> When a Process  writes text to its
>   standard stream, that text is normally
>   displayed on the console. By
>   redirecting the StandardOutput 
>   stream, you can manipulate or suppress
>   the output of a process. For example,
>   you can filter the text, format it
>   differently, **or write the output to
>   both the console and a designated log
>   file.** 
>   [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx)

This post is similar to [Capture standard output and still display it in the console window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786726/capture-standard-output-and-still-display-it-in-the-console-window) by the way. But that post didn't end up with a working sample.

Thanks a lot,

Patrick

Answer (score 1):

you can easily catch all messages using

```
Process build = new Process();
...
build.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
build.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
build.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
build.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
build.ErrorDataReceived += build_ErrorDataReceived;
build.OutputDataReceived += build_ErrorDataReceived;
build.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
...
```

and create the Event build_ErrorDataReceived

```
static void build_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string msg = e.Data;
    if (msg != null && msg.Length > 0)
    {
        // in msg you have the line you need!
    }
}
```

---

I add a **little example**

> [Screencast of the application](http://bit.ly/cOjA1G)
>
> [Solution Files](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/OutputFromProcess.zip) (VS 2008)

Comment: > Normally when you set StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; the console window stays blank.
This is what I don't want :) I like to get the result as a string + the console window should look as usual and display the messages as the occur. 
Thanks Patrick

Answer (score 0):

See this answer here on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255126/acessing-netstat-like-data-with-net/2255159#2255159) which I posted code for a process to exec netstat an redirect the output stream to a Stringbuilder instance. The process creates a hidden window and is not visible...

You can modify the code slightly by changing the values respectively

```
ps.CreateNoWindow = true; <--- Comment this out...
ps.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; <--- Comment this out...
```

Comment: The problem is when I make the window visible it will be blank since the output is redirected. 

Thanks,
Patrick

Comment: @Patrick: Then...change the above ps.CreateNoWindow to true,and make the ps.WindowStyle to hidden...?

Comment: Hi TommieB, sorry don't understand. The reason for my question was that I like to see the output in the command window as usual and I want the output in a string variable at the end.
When you use StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; the console window stays blank... e.g. it doesn't look "as usual" :)

Comment: @Patrick: Sorry, if you redirect output, you will not see anything!