# Monitor process output without stealing it from the shell

Tags: vb.net, redirectstandardoutput

I have a shell program that sends output to standard out and standard error. I am trying to write a program in VB.net which inspects the output in real time and presents summarized information in a GUI. I also want the shell program to continue to display its output in a command prompt as usual. I don't want to just shove the output in a text box because then it seems to lose its color formatting.

I have written code to inspect the output, and it works, but it has the side effect of eliminating the output in the shell window. Here is the code I use to begin redirecting output:

```
Dim info As New ProcessStartInfo()
info.FileName = "foo.bat"
info.UseShellExecute = False
info.RedirectStandardError = True
info.RedirectStandardOutput = True
revProcess = Process.Start(info)
revProcess.BeginOutputReadLine()
revProcess.BeginErrorReadLine()
```

And then I have handlers for revProcess.OutputDataReceived, etc. to do my analysis.

Edit: Looks like there was another question for this, but the answers didn't go anywhere: [Capture and display console output at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453366/capture-and-display-console-output-at-the-same-time) sorry for the repost.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capture and display console output at the same time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453366/capture-and-display-console-output-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this 100% works but it will only show you the results.....

[how to show shell results in vb.net]
'create 1 textbox1
'create 1 button1
'create 1 richtextbox1

### 'in the start up directory of this program make a file could 123.text

Dim read As System.IO.StreamReader
        read = File.OpenText(Application.StartupPath & "\123.text")

```
    Shell("cmd.exe /c" & TextBox1.Text + ">123.text")
    Do Until read.EndOfStream
        RichTextBox1.Text = read.ReadLine & vbCrLf
    Loop
```

---

also code from this link: mediafire.c(o)m/?3i47vg8seani3­j3
or: pastebin.c(o)m/iEhv61jG