# Capture console output without redirecting the existing output

Tags: c#, console

I want to capture the output of a console application in my C# code, but *without affecting the output* of the program itself.

I know how to launch a console application and catch its output (it's described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186822/capturing-console-output-from-a-net-application-c)). But all of the solutions there set `RedirectStandardOutput=true`, which means that the window being opened just stays black. This is of course bad if the window would show progress or require user input. Is there a way to capture the output without changing `RedirectStandardOutput` to true?

**EDIT**
[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput?view=net-6.0#system-diagnostics-processstartinfo-redirectstandardoutput) it says "By setting RedirectStandardOutput to true to redirect the StandardOutput stream, you can manipulate or suppress the output of a process. For example, you can filter the text, format it differently, or write the output to both the console and a designated log file.". But they don't explain how filtering would work. Can I write to the console of another process?

**EDIT2** The linked question doesn't help me, it seems. Since my own application is a WPF GUI app, I can't just write to the console. I need to write to the console of the target app, not my own.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capture standard output and still display it in the console window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786726/capture-standard-output-and-still-display-it-in-the-console-window)

Comment: @KlausGütter Unfortunately not. My own process is a WPF GUI application, so running `Console.Write(...)` with the received data doesn't work.

Comment: Is the console application under your control, i.e. can you make changes to it to explicitely support this scenario?

Comment: @KlausGütter Yes, it is. But changing all output from that application somehow would be a bit of a pain. And it launches further console tools I don't have control over.

Comment: I found that the tool I was going to call already had the logging capability (that's what I was trying to do) almost implemented, so I went down that path.